# Proving $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \geq 1 + \frac{6}{a+b+c}$ if $abc \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

My goal is to prove that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \geq 1 + \frac{6}{a+b+c}$ if $abc \leq 1$, for $a,b,c$ all positive.  I've tried to multiply both sides by $a+b+c$ to arrive at $(a+b+c)(1/a+1/b+1/c−1)≥6,$ but I haven't figured out how to properly use the condition $abc \leq 1$.

Any hints or solution are welcome.

Comment: What is not obvious though is ... what did you try?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I've tried to multiply both sides by $(a+b+c)$ to arrive at $(a+b+c)(1/a + 1/b + 1/c - 1) \geq 6$, but then I have trouble using the condition $abc \leq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried should do the trick.

First, from AM ≥ GM, we get:

$\bullet\quad a+b+c\ge 3(abc)^{1/3}$;
$\bullet\quad ab+ac+bc\ge 3(abc)^{2/3}$;

Since $abc\le 1$, we have that $-abc\ge -(abc)^{2/3}$, so that

\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc-abc)}{abc}&\ge \frac{(3(abc)^{1/3})(3(abc)^{2/3}-(abc)^{2/3})}{abc} \\
&= 6
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! That's clean and elegant.